# Why is the autoHeight property not being recognized?

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to create some columns using the `autoHeight` property set to true. However, I keep getting these warnings:

```
ag-grid: invalid colDef property 'autoHeight' did you mean any of these: suppressAutoSize,headerTooltip,openByDefault,headerComponent,suppressSizeToFit,sort,headerGroupComponent,pivot
<...snip...>
ag-grid: to see all the valid colDef properties please check: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/
```

My column definitions look something like this:

```
const columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Id',
    field: 'id',
    filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
    width: 90
  }, {
    headerName: 'Description',
    field: 'sportLeage',
    filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
    autoHeight: true,
    valueGetter: params =>
      params.context.liveEventsController
        .createDescription(params.data),
    width: 90
  };
```

`autoHeight` is clearly listed as a valid column definition property. Though, in the debugger, I am looking at `colDefUtil_1.ColDefUtil.ALL_PROPERTIES` and `autoHeight` is not one of the available properties.

I am using ag-grid-enterprise v17.0.0.

My thinking is that either my version is out of date or the documentation is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) `v17.0.0` type definition code for [`ColDef` here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/17.0.0/dist/lib/entities/colDef.d.ts)

`autoHeight` is not a property of `ColDef`.

I am currently at [`v17.1.1` and `autoHeight` is declared as `number`](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/17.1.1/dist/lib/entities/colDef.d.ts).

```
/** True if this column should stretch rows height to fit contents */
autoHeight?: number;
```

*PS: The comments suggests that it should be a `boolean`.

Now this reminds me of a saying* ***:)***

> Code never tells a lie, comments however, sometimes do.

Comment: That makes sense. It's just confusing to me since I was going back through old release notes and I keep seeing mentions of the `autoHeight` property there. Eg- v15.0.0 https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=15.0.0